# How to save table in python?

Tags: python, pygal

I am trying to get a table with data saved in svg, pdf or png file. Are there any libraries to do it?

I've tried pygal, but it seems that they provide only charts saving.

Edited: This table is just a couple of arrays with data, and I need to build a nice table from them

Comment: Is it a python table (list)? Or a html table? Please tell us something more so we can help you...

Comment: You need to be more specific. How are you storing things in this table? Is it a list of lists? And why do you want to turn it into an image? Why not save it as a CSV file?

Comment: According to [docs](https://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/table.html), "pygal also supports a html table export of given data using the render_table option".

Answer (score 0):

Use tabulate, the documentation can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)